# Free and open-source Google Maps replacement?

Tags: android, open-source, maps, openstreetmap, google-maps

I'm looking for a free an open source replacement for Google Maps on Android (which does not ask me if I want to add some pictures although I never started Maps this day).

The most obvious answer "OSMand" is NOT a solution since it wants to download a huge load of map data in advance - what I'm looking for is a solution which downloads the map data right as I'm using it and either for a location where I'm currently are aor for a location I'm searching for.

So which free/OS App would work similar to Google Maps?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) in a browser? If not, give more specific requirements. This Question is too general.

Comment: Updated now, and an interesting question. Personally I don't get many of those requests & just ignore them. They are a reminder, though, of just how intrusive technology is. Proabbly just turning of location services until needed would reduce such requests.

Comment: @Basil Bourque what is general in this question? I referenced to the Google Maps app - which should be a well-known application

Comment: @Mawg No, the Question was never updated. The only edit was minor, and even that was inexplicably, perhaps accidentally, rolled back.

Comment: What features from the Google Maps app do you require? Just viewing a map, or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, meanhwile I found something on F-Droid: CityZen.

It is open source, uses OSM and shows POIs close to the own position - and does not seem to be spyware such as Google Maps

Answer (score 0):

OSMand actually supports online maps
Menu > Configure map > Map source... > OsmAnd (online tiles)